# What am I doing wrong with this jwt express middleware?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I am using `nodejs`,`express`, and `jsonwebtoken` for authentication. Once I have verified the token, I keep getting HTTP 404 error once I pass control from the middleware back to the `express` function. Could someone point out what I am doing wrong?

```
//Imports

const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

...

//Middleware 

function jwtMiddleware(req, res, next) {
    const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
    const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1];
  
    // If there is no token, send an error response
    if (!token) {
        return res.status(401).json({
            message: 'No token provided'
        });
    }

    try {
        // Verify the token
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);
        req.user = decoded;
        next();
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(401).json({
            message: 'Invalid token'
        });
    }
};

...

//Function that uses middleware for authentication. In the same file as the middleware

exports.test = jwtMiddleware, (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send({
      message: "Success"
    });   
              
};        
  
...
//Route configuration

router.post("/composer/test", middleware.test);
```

I call the API endpoint `/composer/test` using **Postman: Authorization -> Bearer Token*** and it works as expected when the token is wrong, revoked or missing.

But when the token is successfully verified, I receive the error `404 Not Found`. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do with your `exports.test` assignment?  You're essentially doing `exports.test = a, b;` which invokes the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_operator) which does not seem useful or purposeful here.

Comment: ```exports.test = jwtMiddleware, (req, res) => ```
@jfriend00 With the code above, I am telling the ```exports.test``` function to use the middleware ```jwtMiddleware``` to authenticate. So I expect the request to go through ```jwtMiddleware``` first, and when I call ```next()```, I expect the execution to go back to the ```exports.test``` function and send a HTTP 200 response. I get all the ```HTTP 401``` errors, but when the token verification is successful, I get the ```HTTP 404``` error. That is the issue

Comment: Yes, the issue is clear. But it looks like you're trying to export two functions at the same time (`exports.test = jwtMiddleware, (req, res) ...`) which obviously won't work. You have to export the middleware separately and the success handler separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, now I understand what the issue is.  You need to make `exports.test` an array:

```
exports.test = [jwtMiddleware, (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send({
      message: "Success"
    });   
}];
```

So, that you're exporting an array of two functions. As you had it, you were just invoking the comma operator that would evaluate both expressions, but only assign one of them to `exports.test` thus when you use `exports.test`, you don't get both of them.

What it sounds like you're trying to achieve is essentially this:

```
router.post("/composer/test", [jwtMiddleware, (req, res) => { ... }]);
```

To do that, you need `exports.test` to be an array.

Comment: @morris - Well, you're trying to export two functions.  Those two functions must either by in an object of some kind.  Just putting a comma between them only ends up exportikng one of them.  Using an array is syntactically convenient.  And, it so happens that express route handlers accept an array of functions as one of their arguments, so you don't even have to unpack the array yourself.  You can just directly pass it to `router.post()` as an argument.